# How can I get Kivy Scrollview to stay the same size on different screen sizes?

Tags: python, kivy, label, scrollview, boxlayout

I have a `ScrollView` inside of a `BoxLayout` that changes size rather dramatically when the screen size changes. I am making an iOS app that displays text inside of a `ScrollView` in the top half of the screen, I then have a non scroll `Label` directly under that.

I have been using an iPhone 12/13 for the layout design however when I run it on an iPhone 8 (with the smaller screen real estate), the `ScrollView` overlaps the `Label` text under it considerably. When I run the two different Xcode phone simulators side by side, the `ScrollView` area on the iPhone 8 actually seems to ***increase*** in size for some weird reason.

I have been using `size_hint` and `pos_hint` for all the widgets, which has generally been working okay, just not really with this `ScrollView`. I have tried adjusting all of the sizes of everything but there doesn't seem like a happy middle that I can use to suit both screen types.

I have been using `height` in my `BoxLayout` as the parent for the `ScrollView`, and not sure if I'm using it right either.

I will include my `BoxLayout` with the `ScrollView` in it. Please could someone have a look to see if I'm doing something obviously wrong here? I hope I don't need to make different layouts for every different screen type.

```
BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"top": .9, "center_x": .5}
        size_hint: 1, .3
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 460
        ScrollView:
            Label:
                id: brief_res_1
                markup: True
                font_size: '13sp'
                do_scroll_x: True
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: None
                size: self.texture_size
                halign: "left"
                valign: "center"
                text: ""
```

Comment: I believe you might wanna change your `size_hint: 1, .3` to `size_hint_x: 1` instead, it might help

Comment: I changed size_hint to size_hint_x and made it equal to 1 and changed size_hint_y to equal .3 and that worked super well. Really appreciate it thank you.